# Table align in two column page style in IEEEtran latex

Tags: ubuntu, latex

I am writing a paper using the IEEEtran class. I need to insert a 3 tables in the top of the 3rd page in the two column page style.

my table having 15 columns and 4 rows.....

can anybody tell how to do this.....

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The latex code to solve the above problem.

```
\usepackage{multicol,blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[ht]
 .....
  .....
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```